# Правильно ли расставлены запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

"Инструктор держит вас за ноги, а вы, перекинувшись через край водопада, смотрите вниз!"

Comment: @stardust, не томите! Выкладывайте уж ваше сочинение полностью.

Comment: понимаю интерес к теме:) это о водопаде Виктория. Когда там сухой сезон, есть такая развлекуха: вас подвозят к краю водопада, сбрасывают там в бассейн и вы там плаваете. Для полноты ощущений инструктор может держать вас за ноги, а вы, перекинувшись через край водопада, смотрите вниз. Это проводится только при определённом уровне воды, иначе может смыть вниз со стометровой высоты. можно загуглить и посмотреть фотки - это страшно даже на фотографиях!

Answer (score 1):

Запятые расставлены правильно: ПЕРЕКИНУВШИСЬ ЧЕРЕЗ КРАЙ ВОДОПАДА - деепричастный оборот. 
(Интересная картинка получается!)